# ¿What i am doing wrong?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a table with this sql code:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Proyecto2019`.`matricular` (
  `dni` INT(10) NOT NULL,
  `id_carrera` INT(4) NOT NULL,
  `id_año` INT(1) NOT NULL,
  `id_materia` INT(4) NOT NULL,
  `estado` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `id_login` VARCHAR(10) NULL,
  `fecha_login` VARCHAR(10) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`dni`, `id_carrera`, `id_materia`, `id_año`),
  INDEX `id_carrera_idx` (`id_carrera` ASC),
  INDEX `id_materia_idx` (`id_materia` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_dni`
    FOREIGN KEY (`dni`)
    REFERENCES `Proyecto2019`.`dm_alumnos` (`dni`)
,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_id_carrera`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_carrera`)
    REFERENCES `Proyecto2019`.`dm_carreras` (`id_carrera`)
,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_id_materia`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_materia`)
    REFERENCES `Proyecto2019`.`dm_materias` (`id_materia`)
)
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

And i get the following error:

> 1005 - Can't create table `proyecto2019`.`matricular` (errno: 121 "Duplicate key on write or update")

What is the error? I can't found it

Comment: why do you have CONSTRAINT `fk_id_materia` listed twice?  Looks like you'll only need this constraint once?

Comment: Maybe I'm overlooking something here (probably) but I don't see where the duplicate named index, constraint, or column is here which both the comments and the marked duplicate says is the problem. Am I blind?

Comment: I am guessing everyone was referring to how constraint names, unlike column names, are not table scoped.

Comment: Which then means that there is probably a constraint in the same database that already has the name `fk_whatever` and OP is trying again to use that name? I've not run into this error before so I'm assuming that's the issue that is so obvious to everyone here that they couldn't spell it out for the slow people like me?

Comment: Ah! [Here it is](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html) *The CONSTRAINT symbol clause may be given to name a constraint. If the clause is not given, or a symbol is not included following the CONSTRAINT keyword, MySQL automatically generates a constraint name, with the exception noted below.* ***The symbol value, if used, must be unique per schema (database), per constraint type. A duplicate symbol results in an error.***  That makes me feel better. I'm slow, but I get there eventually.

Comment: @JNevill It's ok, it wasn't the first thing on my mind either; I'm sure i've run into it before though, as it's the only reason I could think for me to name my fk constraints with "thistable_referencedtable_fk" format (redundantly containing the table name). It makes sense because a constraint really is between two tables, not just a property of one (especially when you factor in ON DELETE|UPDATE properties). _It is really more of a syntactic convenience to declare it within the CREATE TABLE._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most commonly this occurs when you already have an FK with that name. Your naming strategy for FKs does look like it would be likely to lead to collision. When I name FKs I put the table and column names in it:

```
CONSTRAINT `fk_mattricular_id_carrera__dm_carreras_id_carrera`
FOREIGN KEY (`id_carrera`)
REFERENCES `Proyecto2019`.`dm_carreras` (`id_carrera`)
```

Names can be up to 64 chars long. Subbing 7 chars for FK and underscores in the pattern `fk_a_b__c_d` means table/column names (a.b, c.d) can be up to 14 chars each (if you want to have a "cut at 14 chars" rule. Which way round you name them is up to you, I tend to do fk_childtab_childcol__parenttab_parentcol

I picked up this habit from old SQLserver I think; the error message used to be massively unhelpful along the lines of "constraint 'fk_whatever' violated" - it didn't say which column referencing what other column was causing the problem but naming the fk well gave more of a clue. It also helps avoid naming collisions as, unless you have two table/columns with very long names that only differ in the last few characters, the chance of a duplication are low

Comment: I had some fk in another table with the same names. Ty to all!